# Streaming audio from headless Ubuntu 12.04 Server to Airplay Speakers (Marantz Amp)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, streaming, airplay

I would like to stream mp3 audio playing locally on my headless ubuntu server to my local Marantz Amp (SR5006) using Airplay. I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I've investigated Shairplay, Pulse Audio - but they either require a GUI or only act as a Airplay receiver. What I am looking to accomplish is have my local server play music from a web interface and either redirect (or change the output sink) the audio from local playback to the amp via Airplay. Is there a way to configure this through Pulse Audio via command line or some other tool via command line?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to another stackexchange.  Maybe even  http://askubuntu.com/?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: Ask Ubuntu


Answer (score 0):

jap, old question. [this even older answer](https://superuser.com/a/345976) suggesting to install package `pulseaudio-module-raop` plus enabling the right pulse-audio setting helped me along the way of solving a similar issue (not headless though).